# error installing react js app "self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, ssl-certificate

I have read all the post related to this and it is not working (or i'm just doing the steps in wrong order). The connection is corporate network. No, the IT people wont help and let me change the https proxy address (because i am learning this now and they don't want any risk)

How to create react app without compromising the security?

Or is there alternative way i can create react app (just for learning purpose) in visual studio code?

[image: cmd screenshot]